# Creating client in Go AWS SDK without session

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, aws-sdk-go

How do we create a AWS service client (e.g. EC2, Autoscaling) without using a session, and instead with directly using the sahred credentials, like in boto3.

Using session like this works:

```
sess := session.New(&aws.Config{
        Region:      aws.String("us-east-1"),
        Credentials: credentials.NewSharedCredentials("", profile),
    })
svc := ec2.New(sess)
```

However, this does not work:

```
svc := ec2.New(&aws.Config{
        Region:      aws.String("us-east-1"),
        Credentials: credentials.NewSharedCredentials("", profile),
    })
```

Error:

> cannot use aws.Config literal (type *aws.Config) as type
>   client.ConfigProvider in argument to ec2.New:     *aws.Config does not
>   implement client.ConfigProvider (missing ClientConfig method)

How to directly create a client with Go AWS SDK without session?

Comment: That's not how the Go SDK works. Why don't you want to use a session?

Answer (score 2):

The SDK needed to avoid a circular dependency, and to do this it used an abstraction called `session.Session`. However, [V2](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/blob/master/aws/config.go#L71-L79) gets rid of this abstraction by flattening some of the packages :)